# Selenium screenshot on loadTimeout

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I m using selenium webdriver(ver 2.45.0 with FFv38.0.5 in my ubuntu 14.04)in my framework which access some url to check its availability and returns screenshots and some data. its all good if the page is up or down and I can get all the data and screenshot, but the problem is when the page timesout, selenium fails to capture screenshot and throws an exception. I tried my best to find some way to get the screenshot from timedout page and failed thats why I m posting it here as last resort. my code as follows,

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver(fbp, profile, desiredCapabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(loadTimeout , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try {
    driver.get(url);
} catch (Exception e) {
   File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);           
   FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("path-to-png"));
}
```

and the exception I get is

```
Could not take screenshot of current page - Error: Page is not loaded yet, try later
Command duration or timeout: 7 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'santhosh-2840', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-37-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_65'
Session ID: a0754b4f-ff3a-4ee1-8ace-6886eaa958b1
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=38.0.5}]
```

Is there anyway to get screenshot from selenium for timeodut pages??

p.s:I do know the timedout pages will not have any dom content on which selenium will fetch content length to calculte its screenshot size, somehow I need to get screenshot for timedout pages also.

TIA

Comment: You mean you can't take a screenshot of the timeout page because there's a timeout? Oh the irony... lol

Comment: @JeffC I understood I cant take screenshot bcoz there is a timeout. I m only asking is there anyway I can get it?? or some workaround??

Comment: Can you add `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.stop();");` into the first line of the exception, and try again? It will stop the loading, and you may get the screen shot.

Comment: @Turcia I tried your code and it didnt work for me, 

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: waiting for doc.body failed

Answer (score 1):

What is the error that you get when you run the code and the page times out?

I think you have to specifically capture a `TimeoutException`:

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    try {
        File source = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        path = "./path/to/screenshots/screenshot.png";

        source.setWritable(true);

        if(source.canWrite()) {
            FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(path));
        }
     } catch(IOException e) {
         // ...
     } catch(Exception e) {
         // ...
     }
}

...

try {
    driver.get(url);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    takeScreenshot();
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: Pretty much I use same technique, excapt I use generic Exception class instead of TimeoutException, can you give me the code snippet of takeScreenshotFunction() method. I use 

File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);           
   FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("path-to-png"));

Comment: Right but if you catch a generic Exception you will catch *every* exception and take a screenshot. What if the exception you catch won't allow for a screenshot? e.g. the browser disappears, etc.

Comment: I had issues with taking screenshots when I used `catch (Exception e)`, so I tried with doing it that way, and it works fine. I will update the code...

Comment: @makeMonday, tried your code unfortunately it didnt work for me, exception as

Could not take screenshot of current page - Error: Page is not loaded yet, try later